# Trying to cut string java

Tags: java, substring, byte

Hi this is my code so the password the user uses is 16 bytes, the code i've written for if the length is shorter than 16 bytes works, however i'm trying to also cut the number of bytes if the user went over, and when I run the code and type more than 16 characters I get this:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 22 bytes
at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineGetKeySize(AESCipher.java:372)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.passCryptoPermCheck(Cipher.java:1052)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1010)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:786)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:849)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1213)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1153)
at Encrypt2.Encrypt(Encrypt2.java:67)
at Encrypt2.main(Encrypt2.java:20)
```

here is the code:-

```
System.out.println("Please enter a password: ");
String passw = input.nextLine();

while (passw.length() != 16) {
    if (passw.length() < 16) {
        int extrareq = 16 - passw.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < extrareq; i++) {
            passw = passw + extra[i];
        }

        if (passw.length() > 16) {
            passw = passw.substring(0,16);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question: what happens when you enter 22 characters?

Answer (score 2):

Properly indented, your code looks like

```
while(passw.length()!=16){
  if(passw.length() < 16){
    ...
    if(passw.length()>16){
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

so the too-long check only runs if the password is initially too short.
You probably meant to do

```
while(passw.length()!=16){
  if(passw.length() < 16){
    ...
  }
  if(passw.length()>16){
    ...
  }
}
```

Proper indenting makes these kinds of errors easier to find.

Comment: Omg thank you I can't believe I didn't notice that after looking at it for so long!

Comment: @ManvirSpeedySinghDhinse, yw.  I'd avoid limiting password/key length in a real system if at all possible.